# Translation of "all of them"

Tags: traduction, pronoms

"I have four dogs. All of them are white."

How should I translate "all of them"? Google Translate suggests simply *tous*.

> (a) J'ai quatre chiens. Tous sont blancs.

Can I specify that it's all **of them**?

> (b) J'ai quatre chiens. Tous d'entre eux sont blancs.

A sentence that means basically the same is the following: "I have four dogs, all of which are white." Can I translate like this?

> (c) J'ai quatre chiens, dont tous sont blancs.

Comment: *Tous sont blancs* or *chacun d'entre eux est blanc* are the only ways I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drop "of them" in French but we usually repeat what is being talked about,though as a subject and not as an object.

> J'ai quatre chiens. Ils sont tous blancs.
>
> J'ai trois paires de chaussures. Elles sont toutes noires.

*Dont* cannot be used with *tous* as you do in (c). It would only work to point to a lesser number.

> J'ai quatre chiens, dont deux sont blancs.

Comment: I confirm. You can never say "*tous d'entre eux*" or "*dont tous sont...*". If you're using one of those you're talking about a fraction of them.

Comment: And if you want to do it in one sentence you can also say "*J'ai quatre chiens, qui sont tous blancs*"